# Route Domain through vpn doesn't work

Tags: networking, vpn, ip, routing, openvpn

I have an openvpn server at home.
I want to route a domain over my vpn. The domain has the same ip add. as the vpn server.(My home ip)
When i add: route add 193.80.102.178 MASK 255.255.255.255 10.8.0.1 to windows then i can't access my lan and domain over the vpn. I just want to route example.com(Home Webserver) through vpn.
The same openvpn config works with my android phone.

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote example.com 1109
resolv-retry infinite
route example.com 255.255.255.255
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
remote-cert-tls server
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
verb 4
```

Comment: Your domain server has the same up address assigned to it has your VPN server? Are they one in the same?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: “The domain has the same ip add. as the vpn server.”  - I am asking if your domain server and VPN server is the same server

Comment: The domain has the same ip as the openvpn server

Comment: How do two devices have the same intranet address? An intranet address is internal to your network, while an internet, is everything outside of your network. Trying to determine if the two servers are the same device or not and your not giving a straightforward answer

Comment: the vpn is in my network and my domain points to my wan add

Comment: I don't know if this is the cause of the symptoms you've noted, but you cannot have the same IP twice in a network. It makes things not work. Start by fixing that.

Comment: In the same lan behind nat but with same public ip add.